# Which D&D 5e materials should I use to playtest One D&D?

Tags: one-dnd-playtest

I'm trying to playtest the new [UA - Character Origins](https://media.dndbeyond.com/compendium-images/one-dnd/character-origins/CSWCVV0M4B6vX6E1/UA2022-CharacterOrigins.pdf) material which says:

> The material here uses the rules in the 2014 *Player’s Handbook*, except where noted.

So I know I should use the PHB. However there aren't enough rules in just the PHB to actually play the game. Should I be using other source books while playtesting?

Comment: For those who experience deja-vu reading this, this is a fixed version of the previous question and a reset seems warranted (and was suggested pre posting). Please judge this question on its merits, not that history.

Answer (score 3):

### Use it with what you usually use

The introduction to the document says:

> This document is the first in a series of Unearthed Arcana articles that present material designed **for** the Player’s Handbook coming out   in 2024

The material is intended to only replace material in the PHB. Normally you would combine the PHB with whatever other books you use: Monster Manual, Dungeon Master's Guide, optionally others.

The One D&D announcement stated:

> The One D&D rules will be backwards compatible, allowing you to continue **enjoying the adventures and supplements you play with today**. Our goal for One D&D is to evolve the game in a way that reflects what players have told us they love and that makes it as versatile as them.

So the goal is to upgrade your experience without invalidating existing investments into adventures and supplements you already made. Hence, it should be possible to use it together with them.

You can expect changes to also come to the DMG and MM, but as they are not circulated yet, you have no way to use those, and in the interim can only use what you have. Once these come out, you should of course use those over the current DMG and MM rules, where they override them.